# Cython function doesn't appear to be called?

Tags: python, cython

I have a very short example of a piece of code that does not run as desired. I have a cdef function defined and its wrapper in cython.pyx. The function itself is meant to return a python object (a list):

```
cdef function(double x, double y, double z, double[:] a):
    print "called"
    cdef double[:] aa = np.empty(10, dtype = np.double)
    #do something to aa array
    return aa

def function_wrap(a, b, c, d):
    return function(a, b, c, d)
```

cython.pyx compiles perfectly fine. Now when function_wrap is called from an external python file importing cython.so, there appears to be no indication that function was called. (For starters, "called" was not printed as desired.) So my question is, why is function not being called, and how can I rewrite my code to get what is desired, i.e. the cdef function to perform an operation on an array and return it so that the wrapper function can return it to the external python file? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your extension was built?  It is not allowed to call extension "cython.pyx" because "cython" is a very special name for Cython.

Comment: @ead It was built (I see cython.so) but even otherwise after changing the name, there was no difference.

Comment: Your code is correct - it works for me. Without knowing exactly how you build and what your system is there is no way of saying what is going wrong.

Comment: @ead Huh OK. So "called" is being printed and you are able to retrieve and use the aa list in the external python file?

Comment: It returns a memory view and not a list, but otherwise as you describe